# Android application web services using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, web-services, jersey

This is my first post here. I have written a Java server application (in Eclipse), which I want to access from an android application. ("hit" it's web services). For example I want to access from my Android application this web service:

```
@POST
@Path("/result")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public synchronized Response result(String s) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Job j = mapper.readValue(s,Job.class);

    final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/amdb";
    final String USER = "root";
    final String PASS = "";

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into results values (' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'"+j.getApotelesma()+"','"+j.getHash()+"')");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return Response.status(200).entity("ok").build();
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: first of all you do not need jdbc driver to be able to fetch data to android from mysql

Comment: you can try `HttpURLConnection` in an `AsyncTask` in order to send data to mysql

Comment: please dont focus on that code, this is just a sample. If you can tell me how to "hit" that web service from an android client. An example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You mean that you want to access the web services that you built from the client? In our case an Android device?

Comment: he means that he wants to insert data to his database from an android device accessing the server url that he has created

Comment: @RomanRozenshtein exactly!

Comment: Do you have some experience with Android development in general?

Comment: @RomanRozenshtein not much experiance, thats why i wanna see an example!

Comment: Well your question is a bit vague, you are asking how to build an application with a specific need and not solving a specific problem you are having, due to that it's harder to answer. Any how you can look here for an example of Json parsing from URL you could customize it for your needs. https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html

Comment: since you are Greek you can take a look at this example https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKiXWWY1ZMMzQ6yaYu2MT_w has lots of examples about inserting/fetching data to and from mysql and JSON Parsing